# Regular expression for no white space at start or end, but allow white space in middle, empty and any 6-20 characters?

Tags: regex

I use `^$|^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$` to achieve:

1. no white space at start or end allow white
2. space in middle
3. empty string

But how can I put the quantifiers to limit character count in between 6 - 20?

The following should pass

```
""              <-- (empty string)
"中文"          <-- ( any character)
"A B"          <-- (allow space in middle)
"hi! Hello There"
```

The following should fail

```
"A"            <-- (less than 2 number of characters)
" AB"          <-- (space at the start)
"AB "          <-- (space at the end)
" AB "
"test test test test test test"  <--- (more than 20 characters included spaces)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\S.{4,18}\S)?$
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bS7jM5)

Answer (score 2):

How about such regex?

```
^$|^\S.{4,18}\S$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vXO-FDL1VZwX4a0M)